# Do you need to include older versions in a clickonce deployment folder for automatic updates?

Tags: deployment, vsto, clickonce

Say clients have v1.0.0.0 of my VSTO addin installed and I want to deploy v1.0.0.1.

If I deploy to a new folder and copy to my update location (only v1.0.0.1 will be in the Application Files folder), will automatic updates still work or do I need to have the old version in the Application Files folder too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it will work. the setup.exe located under the installation root points to the latest version

Comment: Yep, just tested it now...doesn't need the old version in the Application Files Folder. Thanks